# WCF REST. SSL. "Client certificate is required" error

Tags: wcf, https, ssl-certificate, wcf-security, fiddler

I have self-hosted WCF REST service. I would like to use SSL and consume service from browser. I used [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https.aspx) blog post as initial point. Basically following steps:

1. Create and register certificate

   > makecert.exe -sk RootCA -sky   signature -pe -n CN=localhost  -r    -sr  LocalMachine -ss Root MyCA.cer
   >
   > makecert.exe -sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir
   >   LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My
   >   MyAdHocTestCert.cer
2. bind certificate to port

   > netsh http add urlacl url="https://+:8015/" user=Domain\User
   >
   > netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8015
   >   certhash=somehash
   >   appid={601A2F31-E812-479A-B5EA-1B78A9683EE0}

Then I try to call some methods from chrome... and nothing happens.

Here is my WCF config:

```
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Security" name="Microsoft.Samples.BasicHttpService.Service">
        <endpoint address="https://localhost:8015" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" name="test" contract="Microsoft.Samples.BasicHttpService.IService"
          kind="webHttpEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="" />
        <endpoint address="https://localhost:8016" binding="mexHttpsBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="MEX" contract="IMetadataExchange"
          kind="mexEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

WCF trace log shows warning: **Client certificate is required. No certificate was found in the request.**

While using `chrome://net-internals/#events` shows error:

```
SSL_CERTIFICATES_RECEIVED
                           --> certificates =
                                  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                base64 certificate          
                                  -----END CERTIFICATE-----


t=1386677875080 [st= 4]        SOCKET_BYTES_SENT
                               --> byte_count = 59

t=1386677875080 [st= 4]        -SSL_CONNECT

... (send/receive part)...

t=1386677875123 [st=47]        SSL_CLIENT_CERT_REQUESTED

t=1386677875123 [st=47]        SSL_READ_ERROR
                               --> **net_error = -110   (ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED)**

...
```

Here is what going on according to fiddler:

```
Tunel to localhost:8015 (Standart SSL handshaking)
**Request**
CONNECT localhost:8015 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8015
....
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters     below.
....
```

Standard response with server certificate common data.

After handshaking browser sends GET request without any information about certificate or SSL at all and as a result  403 Forbidden.

The funny part is that the first time I did it, I could setup Fiddler with ClientCertificate and use Fiddler as a proxy everything worked(still direct calls from browser without Fiddler didn't work). Now after some manipulations (deleting sslcert, create new certs and so on) I've broken even this Fiddler behavior,so nothing works -- with or without Fiddler...

1) So, what steps did I missed? Should I create or import certificate for browser?

2) Who is responsible for establishing SSL connection, I mean who responded with server certificate?... I guess it is OS part (WinInet.dll). It is definitly not my service,because I didn't specify any certificate info, neither for service nor for client.

3) Should I specify serviceCertificate or clientCertificate in serviceCredentials?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is configured to demand that the *client* send it a certificate that identifies the *caller* of the API. You've described how you've configured the *server* to provide a certificate that identifies the *server*, but you haven't stated that you expect the client to authenticate. Do you? If not, you probably need to get rid of this line:

`<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />`

The server accepts connections via `HTTP.SYS` (`WinINET` is a client stack used by IE, and not Chrome) although I don't know how that's relevant to your question.

Comment: Eric, great, thank you very much! You solved it at one second: after I removed this line, everything works!... But I need to authenticate client too, so this line should be. What steps did I missed related to client authentication? Should I specify clientCertificate in serviceCredentials section? One more question: am I right that connection is secure without client certificate,traffic is still encrypted?

Comment: Traffic is encrypted when using HTTPS. Client Authentication allows the client to supply a cert to identify itself when it connects to the server. (Client certificate authentication is not commonly used outside of high-security scenarios like banking). You can't "specify" a certificate for the client on the server-- the client must itself provide it, which it typically will do if the server demands one *and* the client has a client certificate available. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/03/client-certificate-selection-prompt.aspx for some discussion.